# Is it possible to set a particular item of a LaTeX3 seq?

Tags: expl3, token-lists

I want to use a `seq` as an array and then set a particular item of this array by its index.
 I know that I can access an item via `\seq_item:Nn` but didn’t find out if there's something like `\seq_set_item:Nnn`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \my_seq

\seq_set_split:Nnn \my_seq {;} {a;;b;c;d}

% set item 5 to x
% \seq_set_item: Nnn \my_seq { 5 } { x }

\NewDocumentCommand {\printseq} {}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \my_seq {,~}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
Sequence: \printseq
\end{document}
```

Is something like this possible, or are there other structures in LaTeX3 that I can use as indexed array?

---

#### some background information

I want to use this in a new package, to apply a TikZ style/options to a particular element of a list by giving its number. For example

```
\mycmd[2=red]{a b c b}
```

should process the list `a b a c` as four TikZ `node`s (which works fine) and the second one (`b`) will become red since the applied option is `red`.

Comment: you really want constant time access for an array but a seq access is proportional to the item number. you could use a property list using integers as the keys, or Joseph and Bruno have some experimental array implementations, they'll no doubt be along later:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. I’ll take a look at the property list. — I added some info about the planned usage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I tried property lists but it doesn’t work, can you take a look at my code, please (see my edit)?

Comment: Replace `\prop_get:Nn` by `\prop_get:No` or`\prop_get:Nf`, which you may have to define using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:Nn { No , Nf }`.  Alternatively, you can avoid worrying about expansion by using `\prop_get:NV \l_your_prop \l_your_int`, since the `V` type expansion knows how to extract values of integers.

Comment: Works like a charm with `:NV` :-) Thanks Bruno!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here my first try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \my_seq

\seq_set_split:Nnn \my_seq {;} {a;;b;c;d}


\cs_new:Npn \seq_set_item: Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_if_exist:NTF #1
  { \__tobi_seq_setitem_aux:Nnn #1 #2 #3 }
  { \__msg_kernel_expandable_error:nnn { kernel } { bad-variable } {#1} }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_tobi_tma_seq
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_tmb_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn { Nf }

\cs_new:Npn  \__tobi_seq_setitem_aux:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l_tobi_tma_seq #1
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l_tobi_tmb_seq \c_empty_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #2 -1 }
    {
     \seq_put_right:Nf \l_tobi_tmb_seq { \seq_item:Nn \l_tobi_tma_seq  { 1 }  }
     \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tobi_tma_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    }
 \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tobi_tmb_seq { #3 }
 \seq_concat:NNN #1 \l_tobi_tmb_seq \l_tobi_tma_seq
 }
% set item 5 to x
\seq_set_item: Nnn \my_seq { 5 } { x }

\NewDocumentCommand {\printseq} {}
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \my_seq {,~}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
Sequence: \printseq
\end{document}
```

Please note: This method is really simple. It doesn't care the original numbers of the sequence. If you want to use it inside a package some more tests are needed.

Comment: Thank you. It’s for a package (the on the causes all may question in the last days `;-)` here)

Comment: I found another solution for my real problem but your question answers the question better, so I’ll accept yours `:-)`

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution based on the comments of David an Bruno.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% DEFINE VARIABLES
% sequence to save the word list
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_words_seq
% sequence to proces the hightlight key value pair
\seq_new:N \l_tobi_highlight_seq
% property list to ave the higlights
\prop_new:N \l_tobi_highlights_prop
% process counter
\int_new:N \l_tobi_counter_int

% DEFINE VARIANTS
% we'll need argument variants for these macros
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:Nn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nxx }

% MACRO TO PROCESS HIGHLIGHT LIST
% this macro reads the property list, given as comma
% separated key value pairs
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tobi_evaluate_higlights:n #1
 {
  % clear the properties from last time, otherwiese the highlights
  % will stay permanent
  \prop_clear:N \l_tobi_highlights_prop
  % process the comma separatet list
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    % spilt each list item at the equal sign and store
    % the part before and after it into a sequence
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tobi_highlight_seq { = } { ##1 }
    % set the propertie from the current key value pair
    \prop_put:Nxx \l_tobi_highlights_prop
     {
      % the first sequence item is the key, i.e. the
      % part before the equal sign
      \seq_item:Nn \l_tobi_highlight_seq { 1 }
     }
     {
      % the second sequence item it the value, i.e.
      % the part behind the equal sign
      \seq_item:Nn \l_tobi_highlight_seq { 2 }
     }
   }
 }

% MACRO TO FORMAT A SEQUENCE
% (more complex in real life ...)
\NewDocumentCommand {\printseq} { O{} m }
 {
  % process the optional argument as property list
  \tobi_evaluate_higlights:n { #1 }
  % store the second arguemt in a sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tobi_words_seq {;} { #2 }
  % set the porcess counter to 0
  \int_zero:N \l_tobi_counter_int
  % process each word sequence item
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tobi_words_seq
   {
    % increment the process counter
    \int_incr:N \l_tobi_counter_int
    % draw the item insid a TikZ node and apply the property
    % according to the process counter, it will be empty if the
    % property isn't defined
    \tikz \node [draw,\prop_get:NV \l_tobi_highlights_prop \l_tobi_counter_int] {##1};
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
Sequence: \printseq[2=red]{foo ; bar ; baz}
\end{document}
```